# Alphanumeric & alphabet only Validation in struts2-validation.xml

Tags: validation, jsp, struts2

I am trying to validate textbox in struts2 application of Jsp page. It should accept alphanumeric or alphabet.

I have used following code in validation.xml file:

```
<validator type="requiredstring">
    <param name="fieldname">productName</param>
    <message>Please select product Name.</message>
</validator>

<validator type="regex">
    <param name="fieldname">productName</param>
    <param name="expression">^[,a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$</param>
    <message>Product name should accept only in AlphaNumeric.</message>
</validator>
```

Field name: product Name
Valid Input: abcdABC123(Alphanumeric), abcABC(alphabet)
Invalid: 123(Numeric)

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi everyone..please help me to find solution for the aboove problem. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @what is the problem? what is happening with the above validation rule?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi: when i use the above code, text box accepts numeric,alphanumeric and alphabet also. I want to allow only alphanumeric and alphabet in that text box.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi: Thank you Umesh. Mr. Batbaatar's Answer helped me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
<param name="expression"><![CDATA[^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[,a-zA-Z0-9]*$]]></param>
```

Please read about `MUST CONTAIN` expression from here:

http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-password-with-regular-expression/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Valuable help to solve this issue. I got the solution.